# Change color font of a specific <td> with logic

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a table where the td-s are set like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template v-slot:body="{items}">
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(item,idx) in items" :key="idx">
          <td>{{item.nick}}</td>
          <td>{{item.cat}}</td>
          <td v-for="(header,key) in dayNumbers" @click="edit(idx, header)" :key="key">
            <v-layout justify-center>{{item[header]}}</v-layout>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</template>
```

idx and idy refer to the index of the row and column in the for loops.
items is an object generated from an array of objects where I store  for each day of the month two values, the original and the current. I'd like to change the color of the  where the current data displayed is different from the original value. How could I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Please add the app to the code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `v-bind:class="{ yourStyle: yourCondition }"` in `<td>` that you wanna change color.

Comment: Thanks. I have put a v-bind:class="someMethod(idX, idY)"
and in the method I apply the logic and return the style. It works now.